# Delete items in a list based on its value in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a list of string:

```
List<string> productsAll = new List<string>();
productsAll.Add("CMT_40");
productsAll.Add("CMT_50");
productsAll.Add("Mortar");
```

How do I remove the items at `productsAll` without using `productsAll.RemoveAt`?

I can't delete the value based on index, as `productsAll` will be heavily modified with each interactions in the page.

Comment: If your values are unique I recommend using [Hashset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of List(of String) for efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove item from the list if you know the item you would like to delete

Use

```
productsAll.Remove("item123");
```

Follow msdn link for more explanation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Remove` is a nice option to remove a specific item from the list, if you want to remove more than one elements means you can try `RemoveAll` as well. you can try the following code:

```
List<string> productsAll = new List<string>();
productsAll.Add("CMT_40");
productsAll.Add("CMT_50");
productsAll.Add("Mortar");
productsAll.Add("Mortar");
productsAll.Add("Mortar");
string itemToRemove = "Mortar";

productsAll.RemoveAll(x=>x==itemToRemove);
```

Check [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z6upMp) for working demo. You can also try removing items that contains specific text by using `.Contains()` by using the following code:

```
 productsAll.RemoveAll(x=>x.Contains(itemToRemove));
```